# Dockerfile - RUN unable to execute binary available in environment PATH

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Creating a  `dockerfile` to install dependency binary files:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update \                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    && apk add ca-certificates wget \                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    && update-ca-certificates 

RUN mkdir -p /opt/nodejs \
    && cd /opt/nodejs  \
    && wget -qO- https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.9.1/node-v8.9.1-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xvz --strip-components=1

RUN chmod +x /opt/nodejs/bin/*

ENV PATH="/opt/nodejs/bin:${PATH}"

RUN which node
RUN node --version
```

`which node` correctly identifies the node binary from `$PATH`, as `$PATH` is modified by the `ENV` command before it. However, `RUN node --version` is not able to locate the binary.

The image build logs show:

```
Step 11 : ENV PATH "/opt/nodejs/bin:${PATH}"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7dc04c05007f
Step 12 : RUN which node
 ---> Running in deeaf8e9fe09
/opt/nodejs/bin/node
 ---> 074820b1b9b5
Step 13 : RUN node --version
 ---> Running in 6f7eabd95e90
/bin/sh: node: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c node --version' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

What is proper way to invoke installed binaries during the image build process ?

Notes:

1. I have also tried linking binaries to `/bin`, but `sh` still can't find them in `RUN`.
2. Docker version 1.12.1

Comment: what is your base image? Can you post the Dockerfile please?

Comment: @SRC Updated in question.

Comment: It is not a direct solution to your problem. But if I build my image on the base image of the official [node:alpine](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node#nodealpine) then I can run the `node --version` directly. The flipside is that the base image is bigger in size than the bare alpine image. Although the derived image is smaller in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of node you installed has dependencies on libraries that are not included in the alpine base image. It also was likely linked against glibc instead of musl.

```
/ # apk add file
(1/2) Installing libmagic (5.28-r0)
(2/2) Installing file (5.28-r0)
Executing busybox-1.25.1-r0.trigger
OK: 9 MiB in 15 packages
/ # file /opt/nodejs/bin/node
/opt/nodejs/bin/node: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=862ecb804ed99547c06d5bd4ac1090da500acb61, not stripped
/ # ldd /opt/nodejs/bin/node
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f793665d000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f793665d000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f793665d000)
Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/nodejs/bin/node)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f793665d000)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/nodejs/bin/node)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f793665d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f793665d000)
```

You can find a Dockerfile that installs node on Alpine [from the docker hub official repo](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/bf84a38aeacb4f6aad34e07c79fd3a0084da5cd2/8/alpine/Dockerfile) that would be a much better starting point.

Comment: I think this is the issue. [Here is an alpine image with glibc](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-glibc/) I'll give it a try.